# Change the confirm_form message of an entity made with eck

Tags: 7, entities

I have an entity created with [eck](https://drupal.org/project/eck) module, and when I want to delete an entity the message is :

> Are you sure that you want to delete %id ?

I want to change this message to show me the title of the entity and not the id.
I find where this is implemented, is in the code below in `eck.entity.inc` file located under the eck module folder:

```
function eck__entity__delete_form($form, &$form_state, $entity_type, $bundle, $id){
  $path = eck__entity_type__path();
    
  $entities = entity_load($entity_type->name, array($id));

  $form['entity'] =
      array(
        '#type' => 'value',
        '#value' => $entities[$id],
  );

  $form['entity_type'] =
      array(
        '#type' => 'value',
        '#value' => $entity_type,
  );

  $form['bundle'] =
      array(
        '#type' => 'value',
        '#value' => $bundle,
  );

  $form['submit_redirect'] =
  array(
    '#type' => 'value',
    '#value' => "{$path}/{$entity_type->name}/{$bundle->name}",
  );

  $message = t("Are you sure that you want to delete %id",
          array("%id" => $id));

  $caption = t("This action cannot be undone.");

  return confirm_form($form, $message, "{$path}/{$entity_type->name}", $caption, t('Delete'));
  
}
```

Is there a way to change this confirm message without changing the code of this module ?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use hook form alter to change a piece of the form, see this answer by Clive:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111034/altering-title-on-drupal-node-delete-confirmation-form

Comment: In this case the name of the function should be : MYMODULE_form_entity_delete_confirm_alter ? because this is not a node entity but a custom entity!

Comment: most likely. if you install the devel module in and in the code you have listed above add to the very top of the function (its 1st line) `dpm($form_id, __FUNCTION__);`  you will see the form_id of this form and the function name calling the dpm notice to the page (this function).